# If I answered a question with 4 upvotes and user then gives a bounty, what happens after a week and he hasn't accepted?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Does that also mean that to be "included" in the bounty list, I need to delete my answer and create another answer?

What if I have another answer for the user and edit my own answer? Will I be eligible to the bounty or will I never be eligible as the bounty was created after I posted my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at this the wrong way.

Answers posted *before* the bounty is started aren't eligible for the auto-awarding processes, but there's nothing stopping the bounty being awarded manually. If you delete your original answer and repost *the same answer* a) there's no guarantee you'll get the 2+ up-votes necessary to be eligible for the auto-award process and b) there's every chance that 10K+ users and moderators will spot the behaviour.

If your original answer hasn't helped the OP (despite being up-voted by others) you can either a) delete it (as you originally suggested) and get the Disciplined badge, b) edit it to include the new answer (but perhaps leave the old information there as a reference), or c) add a new answer.

If your answer has 4 up-votes then there's a good chance that the the bounty poster will award your answer the bounty anyway.

Comment: not really, the OP DID try my answer but it didn't work and while I still plan to help him with it, he started a bounty so I was wondering what I should do with my now incorrect answer. I COULD edit it, or I could just delete it(since it was already outdated/wrong) and provide him with a new answer

Comment: @corroded - in that case add a new answer but leave the old one there, edited if necessary.

Comment: do i put in my old answer to check on my new answer? something like "please check my new answer below as this is outdated already"?

Comment: @corroded - you can if you want. The reason I said leave it was that 4 people thought it offered good advice. It might help someone else in a similar situation, but there's nothing to stop you deleting it if you think it's now completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Posts answered before the bounty is started will not count towards automatic awarding.

Comment: yes, but if i edit my post, will that count towards the automatic awarding? or do i need to create a new answer again(if it is possible to delete a +4 answer)

Comment: @corroded, nope, I don't think so. If you have another better answer, you could answer new one, but I am not sure that would attracts up votes